# \Captionbox already defined

Tags: captions

I am using following packages and document class at preamble and at running time, latex editor gives following error. No idea what is happening:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{jwe,epsfig}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage[compatible]{algpseudocode}
```

The error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \captionbox already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal,
```

**EDIT**

```
    \adjustbox{max height=\dimexpr\textheight, max width=.95\linewidth}{
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Regular expression for extracting links within HTML code of Web pages},label=Pattern,linewidth=12cm]

"https?://(?:www\\.)?[^\\n<>\"]+(?:\"[^<]*>([^<]*))?"

\end{lstlisting}
}

\vspace{10pt}
```

Comment: What's `jwe.sty`?

Comment: @egreg That is the journal style file.